# what’s the type of this class member a?

Tags: c++

My code is :

```
typedef double Money;
class Person
{
    Money get(){return a;}
private:
    typedef long double Money;
    Money a;
};
```

I define this class, I want to know the type of `a`: `double` or `long double`?

the return type of function `get()` is `double`, is it right?

I have used function `std:is_same` to test the type of `a`

```
typedef double Money;
class Person
{
public:
    Money get(){return a;}
    void test()
    {
        cout<<is_same<decltype(a), double>::value<<endl;  // false
        cout<<is_same<decltype(a), long double>::value<<endl; //true
    }
private:
    typedef long double Money;
    Money a;
};
```

so the type of `a` is `long double`.

Comment: Test it with `std::is_same` or with an invalid template instantiation (works in GCC at least).

Comment: `typedef` happens in the order it appears in the file, so yes, the return type of `get` is `double`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, GCC actually complains about it with -fpermissive not on, but then goes to say `long double` with the template trick instantiated inside `get`.

Comment: @chris: Good thing I didn't write it as an answer then... ;)

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to represent money as a floating point number, at least as long as the unit is not the smallest indivisible unit. If the unit is dollar, you cannot exactly represent a cent, and round off errors will eventually add up. I would suggest to use a 64 bit int to count cents: its guaranteed to be exact and can even represent the dept of the United States...

Answer (score 3):

In the standard it is said :

> **7.1.3 The typedef speciﬁer [dcl.typedef ]**
>
> In a given scope, a typedef speciﬁer shall not be used to redeﬁne the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to a different type.

It means that C++ requires that `Money` has to be of the same type when it's first seen and later reevaluated.

You program is not valid because the first time `Money` is evaluated it's of type `double` and when it's reevaluated it's of type `long double`... All in the class scope...

If you remove you `get()` function for example, `Money` will be evaluated as `long double` when you will declare `a`.

---

From the comments, I'm trying to explain more what I mean :

Effectively, the two typedefs are defined in different scopes. But during the first evaluation of `Money` (for the `get()` definition), its type is `double`, due to the typedef done in the global scope.

Later, with the second typedef, we redefine `Money` to be of type `long double`.

Here we are trying to redefine a type declared before, in the same scope (class scope).

---

It seems that Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 are ok with that.

I tested it with g++ 4.2.1 and 4.8.1 and I'm getting this error :

```
error: declaration of ‘typedef long double Person::Money’
error: changes meaning of ‘Money’ from ‘typedef double Money’
```

Comment: but i compile it successfully in VS2010? how to explain this?

Comment: Some compilers can accept that, but if you follow the standard, we cannot say which typedefs is used. As hvd said, GCC generates a hard error for this... It depends on the compiler implementation... Is seems that VS2010 and VS2012 are ok with that...

Comment: The original typedef of `Money` is in the surrounding scope, not "in that scope" so this quote doesn't apply.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I was thinking that during the declaration of the `get()` function `Money` is of type `double`, and in the declaration of `a`, `Money` is evaluated as `long double`. In the same scope it seems that `Money` is evaluated with two different types... At least i'm getting an error with my GCC...

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud: gcc may well be correct (I think it is) but it seems clear to me that the two typedefs of `Money` are in different scopes.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The two typedefs are in different scopes, you are right. But what I'm trying to explain is that during the evaluation of the `get()` function(class scope), it inherits from the typedef of the global scope, and later when you define `Money a`, `Money` is redefined with a new type which not correct. (kind of hard to explain...) I will try to modify my post to make a better explanation....

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid C++ code, so there is no answer to your question. C++ requires that when `Money` is first seen, and when `Money` is later reevaluated, it is the same type in both cases. GCC generates a hard error for this. Other compilers may accept it, but if they do, the standard does not say which typedef is used.

If you remove your `get()` function, the type of `a` is `long double`, since the local typedef shadows the global one. In that case, the local typedef appears before `Money` is used, and there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
typedef long double Money;
```

is a give away

i.e. `a` is of type `Money` and `Money` is a `long double`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to check it:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef char Money;

class Person
{
    public:
        void checkType()
    {
        if (sizeof(char) == sizeof(long))
        {
            std::cout << "This test is bullshit" << std::endl;

        else if (sizeof(Money) == sizeof(char))
        {
            std::cout << "It's a char. Global scope is what matters" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (sizeof(Money) == sizeof(long))
        {
            std::cout << "It's a long. Inner scope is what matters" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    private:
        typedef long Money;
};

int main()
{
  Person p;

  p.checkType();

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

And the answer is.... long! (in VS2012, anyway)

Comment: yeah, you can use std:is_same, this function is very handy.

Comment: This does not test the same thing. The rules are different for how `Money` gets treated inside a function definition versus outside of it. Inside a function definition, you can refer to other class members that only get defined later.

Comment: So you are saying this:     typedef char A;
    class B
    {
     public:
      A f()
      {
       A res;
       return res;
      }
     private:
      typedef long A;
    }; might not be compiled because of a type mismatch? (I hope this comment will be posted properly, I'm new for this platform)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the applicable part of the standard in this case is §3.3.7/1:2 and 3:

> 2) A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.
>
> 3) If reordering member declarations in a class yields an alternate valid program under (1) and (2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic is required.

The name `Money` used in the definition of `Person` in the context of the definition of the return type of `Person::get` refers to `::Money`, but when reevaluated in the completed scope of `Person` refers to `::Person::Money`.

Likewise, reordering the member declarations so the `typedef` of `Person::Money` precedes that of `Person::get` yields a an alternate valid program.

As such, it appears that your code is ill-formed, but since no diagnostic is required both VC++ and gcc are equally conforming in this regard. I certainly prefer that the violation be diagnosed (as gcc does) rather than accepted silently (as VC++ does).